# Multiple RouterLinkActive trigger CSS class at the same time

Tags: html, css, router

I'm using multiple `<a>` tags to use routerLink.
When I first load my home page, the home icon (which is in aMenuItems) has the `active` class thanks to `routerLinkActive` and the rest of the array aMenuItems does not. This is a good behaviour.

However, both `<a>` tags in `bottom-group` has the `active` class triggered as the home icon. I tried to set the attribute `exact` in routerLinkActiveOptions to `true` but nothing changes.
As soon as I select another page other than home page, this bug disappears.

HTML:

```html
<div class="top-group">
    <a
        *ngFor="let oItem of aMenuItems"
        class="menu-item"
        [routerLink]="oItem.link"
        routerLinkActive="active"
        [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"
    >
        <mat-icon>{{oItem.icon}}</mat-icon>
        <p>
            {{oItem.designation}}
        </p>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="bottom-group">
    <a
        class="menu-item"
        [routerLink]="routerLinkMarketPlace"*
        routerLinkActive="active"
        [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"
    >
        <mat-icon>apps</mat-icon>
        <p>applications</p>
    </a>
    <a
        class="menu-item"
        [routerLink]="routerLinkSettings"
        routerLinkActive="active"
        [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"
    >
        <mat-icon>settings</mat-icon>
        <p>paramètres</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem:

In HTML, I replaced the `routerLinkActive` with a class condition using the attribute `isActive` from the router.

```html
    <a
        class="menu-item"
        [routerLink]="routerLinkSettings"
        [class.active]="router.isActive(routerLinkSettings)"
        [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"
    >
        <mat-icon>settings</mat-icon>
        <p>parameters</p>
    </a>
```

You also need to inject the router in your `.ts`

```js
    constructor(private router: Router) {
        super();
    }
```

Hope it can help someone passing by !